# NIFI custom processor error - can not upload template

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

Good day,

I'm trying to upload nifi template and getting this kind of error:

org.apache.nifi.processors.kite.ConvertAvroSchema is not known to this NiFi instance

I suppose that my Nifi Instance misses some component - but where can I get it and where on file system I need to add missing file?

I'm little bit confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Migration+Guidance), since 1.10.0 kite-nar was taken out of the default binaries because of space limitations. 
You can get it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kite-nar).